# Could someone explain the chain homotopy between the identity and the constant map on $S_{*}(x)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

For $\epsilon$ : $S_{*}(X) \to Z$
and $\eta$ : $Z \to S_{*}(X)$, it's still unclear to me how's that
$bd* + b*d = 1 - \eta \epsilon$, in a region $X$ in Euclidean space, star shaped with respect to $b\in X$.

Could someone possibly explain how it's derived, and short intuition behind it as well as what it might imply?

Comment: If $\sigma \in S_*(X)$ and $X$ is star-shaped at $b$, then you can construct a homotopy between $\sigma$ and the constant simplex $c_b$ by moving all points of $\sigma$ along the line joining them to $b$.